# Tailwind+Alpine transition to/from opacity-30

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, alpine.js

I'm trying to figure out how to have an overlay div element transitioning from and to opacity-30 when input is provided in a field.

The problem is that after the transition finishes, the opacity goes to 100.
If I put in `opacity-30` in the div's class, the transition won't show.
`:class="{ 'opacity-30': searchQuery.length > 2}"` will neither work as that will insert `opacity-30` at once.

```html
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@v2.x.x/dist/alpine.min.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>

<div x-data="{ searchQuery: '' }" class="p-10">

    Input: <input x-model="searchQuery" type="text" class="w-32 border border-black">
    
    <div x-cloak x-show="searchQuery.length > 2" x-transition:enter="transition ease-out duration-1000" x-transition:leave="transition ease-in duration-1000" x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0 transform"
      x-transition:enter-end="opacity-30 transform" x-transition:leave-start="opacity-30 transform"
      x-transition:leave-end="opacity-0 transform" class="bg-black fixed h-full left-0 top-16 w-full">
    </div>
    
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I think I'm missing something really simple here (-:

Any thought would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which version of Tailwind CSS are you using? `opacity-30` is only available from version 2.x+.

Comment: V2 indeed. Opacity-30 works fine.